# jQuery Live, many times function execution

Tags: jquery

When I use  jQuery `live` function in dynamic pages( pages are displayed via Ajax), the buttons events, detected with `live`, are duplicated. And, every time than I access the page which contains these buttons, one click causes the function execution many times.

How I can fix this?

Comment: You will have to show us your relevant HTML/Javascript for us to know how to help you.

Comment: It is largely depending on how you exactly attach these events (maybe the event is attached to several elements and handlers are called when the event bubbles up), how your HTML looks like (are there any inline event handlers?) and how your handlers look like (eg. if you are having some recurrence or re-attaching of events). In other words: show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have attached the same handler to the same event several times.

Without code it's not possible to provide further help but I'm sure now you know how to fix it yourself :-)

Comment: +1 for actually being correct. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471998/jquery-live-many-times-function-execution#comment16778362_12471998), but you have put it clearly. The handler may be attached eg. to other elements when there is no code preventing bubbling up and they are along the way to the top, but it is still the same handler attached to the same event.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `.on()` and `.off()` as `.live()` was already deprecated and shown a lot of issues

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

what you can do there is to set `.off()` before binding `.on()` to the element so we can ensure that all previous event handlers are remove.

As you don't provided any code I just guessed what was your problem.

I think in every ajax response the DOM changes with the code of calling `.live()` again to listen to the events of the new injected DOM. now from what I am saying earlier `.on()` and `.off()` are already to the rescue. call `.off()` to ensure that all existing event handlers are removed then recreate all the event listeners by `.on()`

Comment: The function `on` work like the function `bind`, but It don't work with dynamical pages. It's ok for the page loaded first time.

I have a table and for each row some buttons. For this table is implemented the pagination. 
For the first page of table, with `bind` the actions are ok, for the next page `bind` don't detect the action. `Live` function works for all pages of tables, but if I load the table many times, every time the actions detected by `live` function are duplicated.

I tried `return false` and `event.stopImediatePropagation()` to stop the iteration of events but this doesn't work.

Comment: well the trick here is to call everytime `.off()` and `.on()` in every DOM change(the dynamical page that you where saying). the `.off()` and `.on()` are created to replace '.live()'

Answer (score 0):

You are probably (inadvertently) re-binding the `live()` event multiple times on the same element (eg the code that binds the live event is repeated several times). Try using `one()`; this will bind just *once*, and will not re-bind if the exact same event has already been bound to the element.

Example usage:

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
    //event on click, bind this just once, even if this block of code is repeated
});
```

Say you bind an event to a link-click using `one()`, it will just perform (and *keep* performing) the action on each click, but preventing it from firing xxx times (xxx being the times it was bound) on each click.